# Issue in redirecting to Next state, before the promise of previous state is not resolved: Angular , UIRouter

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have state say "state A", which loads the controller say "CtrlA", inside CtrlA i have http call(i.e. promise call), before this promise gets resolved if the user click on some other link which takes him to another state say "state B", the user is redirected to state B, in between of redirection if the promise of Ctrl A gets resolved the user is again redirected back to state A.

Please help me to fix this issue.

Expected : On click on some other link the user should be redirected to State B not to state A

Comment: You should pervent him to click anything before promise resolves after that you can allow that.

Comment: In my application i don't have any option to prevent user from clicking it

Comment: you can do it by css by putting an overlay on screen